# AngularJS Unknown Provider ($injector:unpr) on Keycloak Authentification

Tags: angularjs, keycloak

I am desperately trying to get my web app to work with keycloak.
I have already secured my HTTP REST Service and now I want the user to get redirected to keycloak once he calls the app and is not yet logged in, and after that he gets returned to the app and can use the API Services.

To achieve this, I used this example:
    https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/blob/master/examples/demo-template/angular-product-app/src/main/webapp/index.html
And because I use angularJS version 1.7.x, I changed the code based on this mail:
    http://lists.jboss.org/pipermail/keycloak-user/2015-October/003213.html

Still, I keep getting the error:

```
    jquery.min.js:2 Uncaught Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: 
    AuthProvider <- Auth <- authInterceptor <- $http <- $templateRequest <- $route
    https://errors.angularjs.org/1.7.2/$injector/unpr?p0=AuthProvider%20%3C- 
   %20Auth%20%3C-%20authInterceptor%20%3C-%20%24http%20%3C- 
   %20%24templateRequest%20%3C-%20%24route
        at angular.js:138
        at angular.js:4891
        at Object.getService [as get] (angular.js:5051)
        at angular.js:4896
        at getService (angular.js:5051)
        at injectionArgs (angular.js:5076)
        at Object.invoke (angular.js:5100)
        at Object.enforcedReturnValue [as $get] (angular.js:4943)
        at Object.invoke (angular.js:5108)
        at angular.js:4897
```

Here is my code:
scripts in index.html:

```
<script src="static/javascript/angular.js"></script>
<script src="static/javascript/angular-resource.js"></script>
<script src="static/javascript/angular-route.js"></script>
<script src="static/javascript/dirPagination.js"></script>
<script src="static/javascript/keycloak.js"></script>
<script src="static/javascript/admin.js"></script>
```

And my admin.js Angular file:

```
"use strict";  
var module = angular.module('service', ['ngRoute', 'ngResource', 
'angularUtils.directives.dirPagination']);  

var auth = {};
var logout = function(){  
    console.log('*** LOGOUT');  
    auth.loggedIn = false;  
    auth.authz = null;  
    window.location = auth.logoutUrl;  
};  

angular.element(document).ready(["$http", function ($http) {  

    var keycloakAuth = new Keycloak({
        url: 'https://keycloakserver/auth',
        realm: 'realm',
        clientId: 'app-admin'
    });
    auth.loggedIn = false;  


    keycloakAuth.init({ onLoad: 'login-required' }).success(function () {  
        auth.loggedIn = true;  
        auth.authz = keycloakAuth;  
        auth.logoutUrl = keycloakAuth.authServerUrl + 
"/realms/realm/tokens/logout?redirect_uri=https://myapp/admin";  
        module.factory('Auth', function() {  
            return auth;  
        });  
        angular.bootstrap(document, ["service"]);  

    }).error(function () {  
        window.location.reload();  
    });  

}]);  

module.controller('transactions', function($scope, $http, $filter) {

    $scope.transactions = [];

    $scope.submit = function() {
        var myParams = {
                searchId: $scope.search_id

        }

        $http.get('https://myapp/rest/search',{params:myParams}).
        then(function(response) {
            $scope.transactions = response.data;
        });
    };

    $scope.sort = function(keyname){
        $scope.sortKey = keyname;
        $scope.reverse = !$scope.reverse;
    };

    $scope.showDetails = function(transaction) {
        $scope.selectedTransaction = transaction;
    };

});

module.factory('authInterceptor', ["$q", "Auth", function($q, Auth) {  
    return {  
        'request': function (config) {  
            var deferred = $q.defer();  
            if (Auth.authz.token) {  
                Auth.authz.updateToken(5).success(function() {  
                    config.headers = config.headers || {};  
                    config.headers.Authorization = 'Bearer ' + 
Auth.authz.token;  

                    deferred.resolve(config);  
                }).error(function() {  
                    deferred.reject('Failed to refresh token');  
            });  
        }  
        return deferred.promise;  
    },  
    'requestError': function(rejection) {  
        return $q.reject(rejection);  
    },  

    'response': function(response) {  
        return response;  
    },  

         'responseError': function(response) {  

            if (response.status == 401) {  
                console.log('session timeout?');  
                logout();  
            } else if (response.status == 403) {  
                alert("Forbidden");  
            } else if (response.status == 404) {  
                alert("Not found");  
            } else if (response.status) {  
                console.log(response.status);  
                if (response.data && response.data.errorMessage) {  
                    alert(response.data.errorMessage);  
                } else {  
                    alert("An unexpected server error has occurred");  
                }  
            } else if (response === 'Failed to refresh token') {  
                logout();  
            }  
            return $q.reject(response);  
        }  
    };  
}]);  

module.config(['$httpProvider', function($httpProvider) {  
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push('authInterceptor');  
}]);
```

I would be very thankful for every hint! THANK YOU! :-)

Comment: you didn't past relevant code

Comment: Hi, what have i forgotten? Thanks